# Custom channel playlist sync with the server in Xtream Codes

Tags: synchronization, video-streaming, live-streaming, iptv

I am working with Xtream Codes to generate the default M3U URL and EPG URL using the below API calls:

```
http://<-YOUR DNS ->:<-YOUR PORT ->/get.php?username=$username&password=$password&type=m3u_plus&output=ts
http://<-YOUR DNS ->:<-YOUR PORT ->/xmltv.php?username=$username&password=$password
```

Now I want to generate a custom M3U playlist. I have extracted Channels and Groups/Categories from the above API endpoints. I just don't understand how to sync that with the server after I customized the playlist. I have searched on the web, but couldn't find anything related to this. Is there any endpoint for syncing this with the server? I am not able to find anything suitable in any documentation. It will be a great help if someone can guide me.

Answer (score 0):

**The API is read only, you are not able to commit these changes back to the server.**

You may be able to coordinate with the server host to have the changes made their side though this is unlikely.

You could host the changed file yourself, you could use a simple web host like apache but this lacks the security features of a proper streaming software. It’s likely your server provider wouldn’t approve of this either.

If this is for an app, you’d have to modify then cache the file.